# Found a larva in my broccoli, is it a Small White (Pieris rapae)?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

Found this living larva in broccoli from a store. It was about 10 mm long. It was in july this year, and I don't remember the country of origin for the broccoli. A bit of googling makes me think it could be a *Pieris rapae*, but I don't know if there are any similar species.
[image]
[image]

edit: Even if I don't know the origin of the broccoli, I assume (and hope) it was grown in Europe since I got it in Sweden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definately looks like a *Pieris rapae* larvae, which are distinct from larvae in closely related common species as e.g. *Pieris napi* and *Pieris brassicae*. However, I'm not a lepidopterist and there might be related rarer species I'm not aware of, especially since you don't know where the broccoli is from. However, *Pieris rapae* is found basically all over the world as native or introduced (native in Europe, Asia, Africa and introduced in e.g. Ameria and Australia) and is a pest species of cabbage (including broccoli) so it is a very good fit.

Comment: Tried asking in another forum, and no one had an alternative to _Pieris rapae_, so I'll go with that until a lepidopterist objects!

Comment: @picapica Based on your update; if found and probably grown in Sweden, it if definitely *Pieris rapae*. Nice gifs on your tumblr by the way. The spider-killed syrphid fly [here](http://reanimateobjects.tumblr.com/page/4) from 18th Aug. is a *Volucella pellucida* (Fönsterblomfluga), and the beetle below is probably *Phyllopertha horticola*.

Comment: Thanks for the bonus taxonomy, much appreciated. (I don't really dare to use this place to ask about all the animals that I wonder about, that would most likely become spammy...)